# Vim "preview" tab pops-up when selecting a suggestion from autocomplete

Tags: vim

How do I get rid of the preview tab at the top that is popping up when I select an autocomplete suggestion?
[image: video of annoying pop up]

here is my .vimrc mostly copied from someone else(julienschmidt) as I'm new to vim but I see nothing about tags.

```
" -----------------
" General
" -----------------
set nocp                           "enable Vi incompatible features
filetype plugin on                 "per-filetype settings
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2

" -----------------
" Plugins
" -----------------
execute pathogen#infect()


" ----------------
" Encoding
" ----------------
set encoding=utf-8                 "utf-8 encoding
set termencoding=utf-8             "utf-8 terminal
scriptencoding utf-8
set ff=unix                        "unix line endings


" -----------------
" Theme
" -----------------
set t_Co=256
syntax on                          "syntax highlighting
set nu                             "show line numbers
set ru                             "show ruler at cursor pos
set cursorline                     "highlight current line
set hlsearch                       "highlight search results
set showmatch                      "matching parentheses
set gcr=n:blinkon0                 "turn off blinking cursor in normal mode

" highlight the word under cursor (CursorMoved is inperformant)
highlight WordUnderCursor cterm=underline "ctermfg=7
autocmd CursorHold * exe printf('match WordUnderCursor /\V\<%s\>/', escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\'))

"statusbar
set laststatus=2
" ----------------
" Behavior
" ----------------
set ai                             "autoindent
set backspace=indent,eol,start     "allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set shiftround                     "round > < to shiftwidth
set ignorecase smartcase           "ignore case, except if contains uppercase
set noerrorbells visualbell t_vb=  "don't ring the bell
set incsearch                      "incremental search
set mouse=a                        "enable mouse
set mousehide                      "Hide the mouse cursor while typing
set virtualedit=onemore            "Allow for cursor beyond last character
set sc                             "show incomplete commmands
set tw=72                          "textwidth 72 characters

autocmd GUIEnter * set visualbell t_vb=

if has('clipboard')
    if has('unnamedplus')          "use + register for copy-paste when available
        set clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus
    else                           "otherwise try to  use * register
        set clipboard=unnamed
    endif
endif
"go
let g:go_highlight_functions = 1
let g:go_highlight_methods = 1
let g:go_highlight_structs = 1
let g:go_highlight_interfaces = 1
let g:go_highlight_operators = 1
let g:go_highlight_build_constraints = 1
let g:go_fmt_command = "goimports"
au FileType go nmap <Leader>s <Plug>(go-implements)
au FileType go nmap <Leader>i <Plug>(go-info)
au FileType go nmap <Leader>e <Plug>(go-rename)
au FileType go nmap <leader>r <Plug>(go-run)
au FileType go nmap <leader>b <Plug>(go-build)
au FileType go nmap <leader>t <Plug>(go-test)
au FileType go nmap <Leader>gd <Plug>(go-doc)
au FileType go nmap <Leader>gv <Plug>(go-doc-vertical)
au FileType go nmap <leader>co <Plug>(go-coverage)

"Markdown
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.md set filetype=markdown
let g:markdown_fenced_languages = ['html', 'python', 'bash=sh']
"always start in first line in git commit messages
au FileType gitcommit au! BufEnter COMMIT_EDITMSG call setpos('.', [0, 1, 1, 0])

"refresh vimrc after saving
autocmd BufWritePost ~/.vimrc source %
autocmd BufWritePost ~/.vim/vimrc source %
```

The add-ons in my bundle are auto-pairs, nerdtree, vim-airline, vim-fugitive, vim-go, YouCompleteMe. I'm guessing airline or YCM are the issue? Anyway if there's a something I can put in my .vimrc to disable this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the answer myself using trusty google: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/2015. It's a "feature" of YouCompleteMe and can be turned off by placing `set completeopt-=preview` in the .vimrc. I'll leave this for google searches.

Comment: No, it's neither a tab nor a feature of YCM. `:help 'completeopt'`.